# how can create this news ticker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ticker

i have been saw this news ticker at top of :
http://www.aja.ir/portal/Home/Default.aspx
how can create that,what is it's solution? 
i need one sample on javascript or Jquery,or one tutorial about it,
Regards.
Sam

Comment: I don't see a ticker are you referring to the image rotater

Comment: There's a news ticker, but it's all kinds of buggy. Now that I've visited the official Portal of the Iranian Army, I hope I'm not visited by men in black suits.

Comment: It's in the blue bar under the search box (next to the date/time).

Comment: I hope the guy that made that ticker didn't help build the nuclear facilities :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [jQueryNewsTicker](http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/)

```
<script src="/js/jquery.ticker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="homeNews">
    <div id="ticker-wrapper" class="no-js">
        <ul id="js-news" class="js-hidden">
            <li class="news-item"><a href="news.php?i=2">Our New Website Has Launched</a></li>          
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need help about Jquery, I would recommend looking at the Jquery Page and searching for a Plugin there.